# Recommend a Java / Android Game Library - card, board, etc.?

Tags: java, android

My dev team and I are looking to do a game in Android, instead of iPhone for our next sprint iteration. We've been tweaking with [GeekGameBoard](http://bitbucket.org/snej/geekgameboard/) (which we love), and I was wondering if anyone could recommend a similar game library for Java / Android-esque.

- We're not looking for OpenGL
- We're looking for Board Game / Card Game (engine or code framework)
- Also, open-source preferable.

Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mages](http://code.google.com/p/mages/) is the only one I could find that isn't focused on OpenGL.  If you are planning a multiplayer game, its worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks! This looks... amazing. I didn't realize it but, yes it'd be great to push for multiplayer, client-server relationships.

I also found this:
http://www.13thmonkey.org/~boris/jgame/

But I think Mages is incredibly helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Seems mages is dead because android was a moving target.

Answer (score 1):

I know of two libraries for card games :

- [android card view](http://code.google.com/p/android-card-view/)
- [dpref](http://code.google.com/p/dpref/)

Answer (score 0):

I have actually built a Board Game in Android, and created a board game library for it. It can be used to create your own custom board game, by inheriting from the `BoardGame` and `Board` classes.

The library is called `Board` and is on GitHub.

https://github.com/SukantPal/Board

For an example customization, look at the Board.Permainan (Surakarta) library that depends on Board library: https://github.com/SukantPal/Board.Permainan